# jQuery and CSS drop down, hover and drop downs disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I see a lot of people have asked about this problem, but none of what i've found has helped. I have a dropdown that displays on hover of list link, and first link in drop down hovers no problem. But, when I hover on the second link the drop down disappears. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/yoq0wyds/

Comment: If the editor says that you should add code if you link a jsfiddle you can of course cheat the system by adding bogus inside a code block, but that doesn't make your question any better. You'll only attract down and close votes to your question. If the editor refuses to save your question, FIX YOUR QUESTION INSTEAD OF TRYING TO CHEAT THE SYSTEM.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the hard width you have applied to your `ul` element.

```
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
    /* width: 24px; */
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ece6e8;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #d9ced2;
    border-top: 0 none;
}
```

[Function example](http://jsfiddle.net/m1xcf0f8/)

Comment: huh, for some reason, second selection still causes the drop down to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

width is not 24px.  hover works fine, but only in the first 24px.  remove the width setting and this works fine.

```
...
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
  width: 24px;
...
```